# How to show the count values on the top of a bar in a countplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have plotted a countplot for the umpires who have umpired the  maximum number of matches in a cricket tournament.
The code used is:

```
  ax=matches['umpires'].value_counts().head(10).plot.bar(width=.8)
```

This plots the bar properly but the exact value of the count is not displayed on the top of each bar.

How do I show the exact numbers on each bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seaborn: countplot() with frequencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179122/seaborn-countplot-with-frequencies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need loop by [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and add new labels:

```
np.random.seed(100)
L = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
matches = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(L, size=(30,1)), columns=['umpires'])
#print (matches)

s = matches['umpires'].value_counts().head(10)
print (s)
C    5
Q    3
E    2
P    2
V    2
Y    2
H    1
D    1
M    1
J    1
Name: umpires, dtype: int64

ax=s.plot.bar(width=.8) 

for i, v in s.reset_index().iterrows():
    ax.text(i, v.umpires + 0.2 , v.umpires, color='red')
```

[image: graph]

Comment: tried your suggestion but the number does not move up. So in your coding `v.umpires + 0.2` does not work for me, the value is directly on top. Configuring the value of `i` moves the number left or right but no luck with the hight. Any idea why?

Comment: @MaMo - Hard to know, I just test it in spyder with `matplotlib: 2.0.0` and `pandas: 0.22.0` and working nice.

Comment: @MaMo - Problem with sample data from answer too?

Comment: no, those work. My coding is almost the same except of the values and if I print what you named `s`, I also get a list looking like yours. No clue what is wrong especially because configuring `i` works

Comment: @MaMo - unfortunately I have no idea :(