# How to have relative frequencies histograms in seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, distribution

I'd like to make a jointplot to compare the distributions of 2 conditions, but one of the conditions has much fewer cases, so its histograms is not visible on the x and y margins. I tried to get normalized histograms per condition with:

```py
sns.jointplot(x=var_x, y=var_y, data=df, kind="kde", hue="condition", alpha=0.7, joint_kws={'norm_hist':True})
```

I also tried `norm_hist={'norm_hist':True}` and `normalize` instead of `norm_hist`, but it didn't work. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46018032/4890633) about `distplot`, but the argument `norm_hist=True` doesn't work for `joinplot`. I had looked at the source code but there is too much abstraction for me to see how I could tweak it to get normalized histogram.
Would you have any idea of how to get that results?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns.jointplot(..., kind='kde')` uses `sns.kdeplot` both for the central ("joint") and the marginal subplots.  You can set `common_norm=False` to either or both of them.

Also note that `distplot` is an old function; seaborn's interface has been cleaned up and extended.

Here is an example:

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')[:230]

sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species", kind="kde",
              joint_kws={'common_norm': False}, marginal_kws={'common_norm': False})
```

[image: sns.jointplot with common_norm=False]
`penguins.value_counts('species')` shows the uneven counts:

```
species
Adelie       152
Chinstrap     68
Gentoo        10
```